# How do I write my application errors to a file in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a small application written in ASP.NET MVC 5. Some of my users are getting errors when an ajax request take place. I am trying to see if there is a way to trace there errors that already happened?

Will the frame work automatically log the application error somewhere where I can view? Or, do I have to add a log manually when needed?

How do I write logs to ASP.NET MVC from the controller?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-Apache-log4net-0d969339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some critical errors from the application might be logged and can be seen in the Windows Event Viewer. But it's possible that only crashing events are logged there.

You should use **log4net** it's an amazing logging library. It has a lot of configuration options to log to a file, to a database and others. It can be added as a nuget package.

You can find a tutorial in [log4net tutorial](https://csharp.today/log4net-tutorial-great-library-for-logging/) and aditional info in the homepage [Apache Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

It's worth mentioning that it will only track errors that happen on the server side and you will have to manually log the error for example in catch clauses. If you want to catch error produced in the browser for example angular, or cross domain issues it won't help you.

Comment: Thank you. Log4net gave me what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are some , I recommend using [Elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)

It's easy to install and configure , Better to use it via nuget